# Is it possible to change the frequency of bluetooth transmission in Android? Maybe through NDK?

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

I know every device transmits bluetooth at a different frequency. Any way to change the frequency. I want to change the frequency of BLE specifiaclly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should research your question before asking. You  should define what you mean by `frequency` since Bluetooth covers a number of protocols, i.e. classic Bluetooth vs Bluetooth Low Energy and radio implementations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Implementation

Comment: yes thank you. Can i change the frequency of BLE specifically

Comment: Do you mean which channels (=frequencies) to advertise on?

Comment: Do you mean change how often you are communicating, or change the radio frequency on which you are transmitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the radio technology used in Bluetooth Low Energy is known as [frequency hopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-hopping_spread_spectrum) the answer is **NO** not as a developer as that belongs to the BLE driver level.

Realize that the range frequencies used to communicate between devices are collectively grouped into channels and that Bluetooth can switch between channels at [1600 hops per second](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2012/ph250/roth1/) so the notion of a third-party app being able to modify a lower level protocol seems undesirable as simply a security and separation of concerns matter.

**Update**

> is it possible to change it at a device level. when i add a Bluetooth component(peripheral) to the device

Without more detail as to what and how you want to change the radio, I can't say. However:

> What if I'm building the device from scratch

You'll need to learn how to read a [datasheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datasheet) which is provided by the chip/peripheral manufacturer. The datasheet will provide detailed physical connection information and details about the wire/software protocols necessary for operation. The datasheet for a chipset is roughly the API to the hardware, generally obtainable by using your favorite search tool, so if you do have a specific modification in mind, the datasheet should inform what is possible or not.

At this point you are at a level below the types of programming questions that StackOverflow normally operates at and should look to: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is it possible to change it at a device level. when i add a Bluetooth component(peripheral) to the device. Im building the device from scratch